# can anyone explain how data is saved in parse without defining any model classes in android? i want to create a similar model

Tags: android

i want to implement a structure in an android project where i can send and retrieve data in a generalized way without creating any model classes ? Please help.i tried it but could not get the desired results.

Comment: " tried it but could not get the desired results" what you have tried to get what results?  please describe your question to more specific about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is extremely vague. However, there are lots of ways of handling structured data without creating model classes, e.g. JSON (see org.json)